# Trying to find the name of a song/PV from Miku Hatsune

Tags: music, vocaloid

As Miku kind of falls under the purview of the Anime/Manga Realm with her image, and PV's I suppose she belongs here.

The PV for the video started out with miku in a lab, she finds a "scouter" like object which translates alien language allowing her to take control of the spaceship she somehow enters, she then enters a "faster than light" sort of warp and heads to like a space mall, things happen and then she "wakes up" at the desk where she originally was.
I think the technology was like "xeno" something or other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it!

Thanks to people who searched, it took me until page 20, going through Miku's *Innocence* song, and then a little bit further to find it.

[Hatsune Miku "Escape", 3D Music Video in Sci-Fi style](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yM0_0oSdwc8)

It's called **ESCAPE**. The "xeno" part referred to "Xenolinguistic".